# Need help! How to get info from another class and use on a Google Mark

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, crud

I have another class called CadActivity where i define the Tittle mark using a EditText. How can i use this information inside onMapLongClick?

Any help will be great :)

```
public class MapaActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener  {

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment meusupFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map = meusupFragment.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng coord) {
    //Intent cadmap = new Intent(this,CadastrarActivity.class);
    //startActivity(cadmap);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coord)
            .title("")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

}
```

}

Comment: Does the code above not work/do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference it in the method, like so (notice the `EditText` variable, the call to get the layout reference and then setting the title using the text in it):

```
public class MapaActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener  {

GoogleMap map;
EditText myText;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment meusupFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragment.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myText = (EditText)myFragment.findFragmentById(R.id.name_of_your_edit_text);

    map = meusupFragment.getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this); 
}

    @Override public void onMapLongClick(LatLng coord) {
    //Intent cadmap = new Intent(this,CadastrarActivity.class);
    //startActivity(cadmap);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coord)
            .title(myText.getText().toString())
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

    } 
}
```